# is there any way to get image using latitude and longitude based on time?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I am currently using google static maps api to get the image using center - longitude and latitude. Is there any way to get the image based on time like in 2016, 2017 etc for the same lat, long?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, Google Static Maps API doesn't have any option to show historical satellite imagery. There is a feature request in Google issue tracker for this feature. You can see the feature request here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35826354

Feel free to star the feature request to add your vote and subscribe to notifications from Google.